# There is any better way for select command during the login?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, scala

I am using select query at the time of login, there is any better way for checking the user name and password. Because i am checking username and password in whole table it is time consuming process if i have 1000000000 or more record then there may be problem. If all user are login at the same time then normal select query is not efficient way.
I am using my sql and scala for developing my college project.

```
select username from loginTable where id='xyz' and userName='john'
```

Comment: Your query should work.  Make sure that you create indexes on the columns you use in WHERE clause.

Comment: usually I use this too. interested to know if there is other way to do this

Comment: What significance does the "id" column have? Does it contain the same data as "userName"?

Comment: i think no other way if username and password is only the info you have in table. without this how can you compare the value?... just increase your efficiency by creating index on both the fields

Comment: question should be how to improve efficency of this query

Comment: sir, can i make the select query fast. there is any alternative ?

Comment: sir ,what about the procedure, if i use my query with procedure it is good way or not?

Comment: BTW, storing plain text passwords in database is not secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because i am checking username and password in whole table it is time consuming process if i have 1000000000 or more record then there may be problem.

That's precisely what the indexes are for. If you have an index on `id`, the database *won't* have to check the entire table for a query which includes `where id='...'`. And if `id` is a primary key, or at least unique, it will automatically have an index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of * make sure you select only columns you really need. Also, make sure your table is indexed.

Comment: * is the example. my query is select id, password from loginTable where id='1' and password='123'. there is any optimize or any way that makes fast execute.